# How to check if a text field is blank or not using Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a text field which is blank initially. How can I check if this text field is blank or not using Ruby on Rails.

I am using rails version-3.2.19 and ruby version 1.9.3.

Comment: you want to check inside _views_ ?

Comment: Hi Arup Actually I want to check whether this text field is containing some value or it is blank.

Comment: Yes,.. but from where ? controller, model, or in view? And if you are in client side, then JS is also there to check ..

Comment: Suppose inside view I have a text field.I want to check inside controller page.Can you please give one example using some code ?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I understand your question, but assuming our field is named `foo` then you can do something like this in your controller method:

```
if params[:foo].blank?
  # the parameter foo was blank
else
  # there was something submitted 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want check it before the form being submitted - this need to be done using JavaScript.

If is in the backend, you will have the `params[:field_name]` available in your controller.